# Fetching the values of multi-level linkedhashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a linkedhashmap which is having String values and collection of few other linked hashmap.

I need to fetch all the values.

Here is my code:

```
HashMap<String, String> lhm =  new HashMap<String, String>();
//********Code to assign lhm *******

System.out.println("LHM="+lhm.values());
```

Output:

```
LHM=[{SchemaVersion=1.0, AgentVersion=3.0.1.31, ServiceTag=XXXX, Model=Latitude E7240, Registered=true, OSVersion=10.0.14393, SPVersion=0, UTCDate=2018-08-28T17:38:57.5935378Z, BIOSVersion=A25, Status=Informational, Description=No Failures detected; High Memory Usage; High CPU Usage}, {LocalDate=2018-08-28T23:08:57.6080352+05:30, LastBootUpDate=2018-08-28T23:05:36.48659, WindowsUpdatedRunDate=0001-01-01T00:00:00, ApplicationCrashesLast24hrs=0, SystemDriveFreeSpace=202.30 GB, HighMemUsage=82.8125, HighCPUUsage=100}, XXXXXX$$2313213132132131233]
```

LHM Object in Debug mode: [image: LHM Object in Debug mode]

Comment: what do you mean "I need to fetch all the values"? you just did with `lhm.values()`

Comment: a `Map` that is defined as `<String, String>` cannot be "multi-level" it can only store `String` values

Comment: @ Sharon Ben Ashe, I need to get the individual values to be assigned to variables.

Comment: what can be the solution instead of map of <String, String>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to store multi-level maps then the map needs to be defied as `<String, Object>` and then you need to query the type of the value in order to get it

```
Map<String, Object> lhm = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Object> subMap = new HashMap<>();
subMap.put("SchemaVersion", "1.0");  // storing String value
lhm.put("my-map", subMap);  // storing Map value

// retrieval: need to query actual type of value
Object value = lhm.get("my-map");
if (value instanceOf String) {
   String strValue = (String)value;
   // process String value
} else {
   Map mapValue = (Map)value;
   // process Map value
}
```

but as you can see this is cumbersome and prone to errors.
a hierarchical data structure like a `Tree` would be much better.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to get the individual values to be assigned to variables

Then just do that:

```
String varA = lhm.get("key A");
String varB = lhm.get("key B");
```

Basically, that is the only way to extract values into variable in Java. You have to `get()` them one by one.

Please note: your code declares the map as `Map<String, String>`, there is no nesting here, keys and values are both strings. Given your current input, nothing else but a simple `get()` is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your output, it seems your HasMap is having String of JSON objects.

for you to extract the values of the JSON objects you can use any of the available JSON utilities and parse the values to an object that you can access its properties and values.

I hope this will help.